# nltk sentence tokenizer gives AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, text-mining

I am very new to python and NLTK. 
One issue is baffling me:

When I do

```
tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize("some long text")
```

It gives me perfect result. But when I change this hard coded string to a variable containing huge text, it gives me the error mentioned in subject viz:

```
tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
...
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'abbrev_types'
```

Below is my full code:

```
from __future__ import division
import urllib.request
import csv
import nltk
from string import punctuation
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer

comments = open("CNPS_Comments.txt").read()
comments_list = comments.split('\n')

custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(comments_list[:300])
##tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize("some long text")
text=""
for comment in comments_list:
   text += comment

tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
def process_content():
  try:
    for i in tokenized[:5]:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        print(tagged)

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))


process_content()
```

I started with python today and there could be many things I am not doing effectively here.

Comment: for comment in comments_list:
   text += comment 

this looks bad because I could have used the 'comments' object itself instead of 'text'. But I tried that too and it did not work.

Comment: this code converts a list to a single string. There are better ways, but you're wrong that it's not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line that's giving you trouble is correct: That's how you're supposed to use the sentence tokenizer, with a single string as its argument. You're getting an error because you have created a monster :-)

The Punkt sentence tokenizer is based on an unsupervised algorithm: You give it a long text, and it figures out where the sentence boundaries must lie. But you have trained your tokenizer with a *list* of sentences (the first 300 elements in `comments_list`), which is incorrect. Somehow the tokenizer doesn't notice, and gives you something that errors out when you try to use it properly.

To fix the problem, train your tokenizer with a single string. You can best join a list of strings into one like this:

```
tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(" ".join(comments_list[:300]))
```

PS. You must be wrong about it working successfully when you tokenized a literal string. Certainly there were other differences between the code that worked, and the code in your question.

Comment: Great! Looks like its working now. So issue is training the tokenizer with list of sentences. Any reason why is this incorrect - I assumed I was training it with 300 different comments.

Comment: Because it's an unsupervised algorithm. You don't give it pre-separated sentences, so a single text is enough. (If your comments might each contain multiple sentences and you're asking why you can't train with multiple texts: because nobody bothered to implement it.)